# Row not deleting in datagrid C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, datagridview

I would like to delete a row from my `DataGridView` after selecting it and pressing delete button. it does work if i have an id or `int` as first column input. but right now i have a `nvarchar` type one. so how do i fix getting `input string is not in correct format`. Here is my code

```
// No row selected no delete....
if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count == 0)
    return; // show a message here to inform

// Prepare the command text with the parameter placeholder
string sql = "DELETE FROM cabphase3 WHERE driver_name = @rowID";

// Create the connection and the command inside a using block
using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\mrdar\source\repos\HTC\HTC\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True"))
using (SqlCommand deleteRecord = new SqlCommand(sql, myConnection))
{
    myConnection.Open();

    int selectedIndex = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index;
    // gets the RowID from the first column in the grid
    int rowID = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1[0, selectedIndex].Value);

    // Add the parameter to the command collection
    deleteRecord.Parameters.Add("@rowID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = rowID;
    deleteRecord.ExecuteNonQuery();

    // Remove the row from the grid
    dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(selectedIndex);
}
```

Comment: Evaluate "i have a nvarchar type one"  and "int rowID = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1[0, selectedIndex].Value);", and start thinking about what might be wrong...

Comment: @Luuk what should be instead of ToInt32

Comment: I hop you do know what this line of code does do: `Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1[0, selectedIndex].Value);`   If you know that, then you also will now that you want to do something different now.

Comment: @HaramHoe check the value of `dataGridView1[0, selectedIndex].Value`. you will get the root cause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private int rowIndex = 0;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int)); 
            dt.Columns.Add("Publisher Name", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Book", typeof(string));

            for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++) 
            { 
                dt.Rows.Add(i, "PubName" + i, "Book"+i); 
            } 
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            this.dataGridView1.RowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Bisque;
            this.dataGridView1.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Beige;
        }



        private void dataGridView1_CellMouseUp(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right) 
            {
                this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Selected = true; 
                this.rowIndex = e.RowIndex;
                this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell = this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1];
                this.contextMenuStrip1.Show(this.dataGridView1, e.Location);
                contextMenuStrip1.Show(Cursor.Position);
            }
        }

        private void contextMenuStrip1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!this.dataGridView1.Rows[this.rowIndex].IsNewRow)
            {
                this.dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(this.rowIndex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

http://csharp.net-informations.com/datagridview/deletegridview.htm